# Buttons clicks and HashMap Android Studio

Tags: java, android, onclick

I'm trying to use the randomVideo variable in my method, but each time I click on ANY button, the variable RandomVideo gets a new String.

But I want to keep the randomVideo as it is Unless the button youtube_random is clicked and not any button.

Cause  each time I click english_button or spanish_button , it's changing the randomVideo variable to something else (I do not want that)
And if I declare randomVideo variable inside the youtube_random button, I cannot use the variable with the other buttons.

```java
public void onClick(View v) {
  String randomVideo = (String) videos.getVideos().keySet()
     .toArray()[new Random()
     .nextInt(videos.getVideos().keySet().toArray().length)];
  switch(v.getId()){
    
    case R.id.youtube_random:
          mYoutubePlayer.loadVideo(randomVideo);
    
       case R.id.english_button : 
                    if (videos.getVideos().get(randomVideo).equals("English"))
    
                        btnEnglish.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    else{
                        btnEnglish.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
    
          case R.id.spanish_button:
                    if (videos.getVideos().get(randomVideo).equals("Spanish"))
                        btnSpanish.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    else{
                        btnSpanish.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Declare the variable in the scope it is needed, but set its value on the appropriate button press.

Comment: Define it globally

Answer (score 0):

Define the `String randomVideo` globally then inside your youtube random button click assign its value as `randomVideo = (String) videos.getVideos().keySet().toArray()[new Random().nextInt(videos.getVideos().keySet().toArray().length)];`